# Naming Lots of Input Checkboxes with a Counter

Tags: javascript, html

This is a pretty straightforward question, but I wasn't able to find the answer to it.

Is it possible to do something like this with JavaScript and HTML?  So below the names of the checkboxes in order would be 1, 2, 3, 4

```xml
<input type="checkbox" name=counter()>
<input type="checkbox" name=counter()>
<input type="checkbox" name=counter()>
<input type="checkbox" name=counter()>
```

```js
function counter() {
  i++;
  return i;
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense what you are trying to do. a name cannot start with a number, or BE a number.

Comment: possible? yes. advisable? only if the checkboxes are created dynamically, in what case you would know how to increment the counter, so, no.

Comment: @deathApril - He could in theory iterate them using underscore.js or jQuery and modify the attributes that way.

Comment: Yes, use `document.write(...)`. Well, better don't. ;-)

Comment: @Barry Chapman - it saddens me deeply people nowdays try to do anything simple with bloated libraries. iteration can be done with super simple JS code.

Comment: underscore.js isnt exactly a bloated library compared to some of them out there :)

Comment: @BarryChapman if the list of checkboxes is known, the names should be assigned when HTML is created (either PHP/... or manually)

Comment: This is true, but in the case of having dynamically added fields, it would be quite overkill to regenerate the form via php in order to get the next index

Comment: for dynamically added elements you can concatenate a number to the string before outputing as HTML, why use countles DOM operations instead of 1??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but yes in a different way. Don't include the `name` attribute (or set the value as `""`), and put this code after your checkboxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chx = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < chx.length; i++) {
        var cur = chx[i];
        if (cur.type === "checkbox") {
            cur.name = "checkbox" + i;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bLRLA/

The checkboxes' names will be in the format "checkbox#". This starts counting at 0. If you want to start the names with 1 instead (like you did say), use `cur.name = "checkbox" + i + 1;`.

Another option for getting the checkboxes is using:

```
var chx = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

With this, you don't have to check the `.type` inside the `for` loop.

In either case, it's probably better not to use `document`, and instead use some more specific container of these elements, so that not **all** checkboxes are targeted/modified...unless that's exactly what you want.

In the demo, I added extra code so that when you click on the checkbox, it will `alert` its `name`, just to prove it's being set properly. That code obviously isn't necessary for what you need....just the code above.

This code could be run immediately after the checkboxes, at the end of the `<body>`, or in `window.onload`.

Comment: Or you could wrap them in window.onload

Comment: @BarryChapman Very true. I just thought doing it as soon as possible might be "best". Also, I didn't necessarily mean "immediately after your checkboxes", so this could go at the end of the `<body>`. I'll still add that to my answer though

Answer (score 2):

You can get a [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) of all `input`s on the page and then loop through them adding the loop `index` to whatever the common [name string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.name) you want for those that have a `type` of `"checkbox"`. In the following example I have used [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to treat the array like nodeList as an array, to make looping simple.

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function (input, index) {
    if (input.type === "checkbox") {
        inputs.name = "box" + index;
    }
});
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/p6ft3/)

Finally, though this has been demonstrated as possible, I think you need to be asking yourself the question "why would I do it this way?". Perhaps there is a better alternative available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're most probably processing the form server-side. you can possibly not bother altering the form markup client-side. For example, simple changing your form markup to the following will do the trick:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="One" name=counter[]>
<input type="checkbox" value="Two" name=counter[]>
<input type="checkbox" value="Tre" name=counter[]>
<input type="checkbox" value="For" name=counter[]>
```

Then, for example, using PHP server-side:

```
<?php 
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['counter'] ) ) {
    print_r( $_REQUEST['counter'] ); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are they "most probably processing the form server-side"? I don't see a form. And the point is how to generate the names in the first place, they didn't say anything about processing it later

Comment: It's reasonable to assume form elements belong to a form.

Comment: Sure, it's plenty reasonable, but this question has nothing to do with how the form or checkboxes are processed on the server. It has to do with generating the name. All you did was type in a new name.

Comment: This will in the future be used as a form with php, I was asking the question generally but thanks for this answer, it gives me another option to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off creating the elements in code. add a script tag in replace of your controls and use something like this (create a containing div, I've specified one named container in my code below)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.setAttribute('name', 'chk' + i.toString());
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(el);
}
```